# Seletor ou Script para atribuir conteúdo diferente a elementos com a mesma classe

Tags: jquery, html, css

Podemos atribuir um título (atributo `title`), a um elemento com marcação no HTML, que tenha essa classe, dessa forma:

```
$(".title-texto").attr("title", $(".title-texto").text());
```

Exemplo da marcação no HTML com apenas um elemento com a classe:

```
{<ul class="miniaturas">
   <li>
     <a href="link1.html">
       <img src="img/imagem1.png" > 
       <p class="title-texto" >texto 1 escrito no html, com o title atribuido no Jquey</p>
     </a>
   </li>
 </ul>}
```

Como poderia atribuir `title` diferentes aos elementos `<p>` que tem a mesma classe?

```
<ul class="miniaturas">
  <li>
    <a href="link1.html">
      <img src="img/imagem1.png"> 
      <p class="title-texto" >texto 1 escrito no html, com o title atribuido no Jquey</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="link2.html">
      <img src="img/imagem2.png"> 
      <p class="title-texto" >texto 2 escrito no html, com o title atribuido no Jquey</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="link3.html">
      <img src="img/imagem3.jpg"> 
      <p class="title-texto" >texto 3 escrito no html, com o title atribuido no Jquey</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Aprimorei a formatação da pergunta, alguma coisa que tenha ficado mal, por favor corrige ou avisa-me.

Comment: Tudo bem, ficou melhor; estou aprendendo com os mestres. ;) vlw!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problema

O que está a falhar no teu código é que estás a dizer que pretendes ir a todos os elementos com a classe de CSS `.title-texto` e adicionar um atributo `title` com o valor do texto de todos os elementos com a classe de CSS `.title-texto`, ou seja, estás a ir a todos e a adicionar o texto de todos em cada um:

[Exemplo do **problema** no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/gtPQS/)

```
// em todos os elementos com a classe de CSS ".title-texto",
// pegar no texto de todos e meter como título
$(".title-texto").attr("title", $(".title-texto").text());
```

## Solução

Para que te possas referir a cada elemento no sentido de pegares no texto do mesmo e aplicares com título dele próprio e não de todos, deverás percorrer os elementos com a classe de CSS `.title-texto` um a um, aqui ilustrado através do uso da função de jQuery [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>:

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/X7Bwp/)

```
// por cada elemento com a classe ".title-texto"
$(".title-texto").each(function() {

    // colocar em cache o elemento actual (eu)
    var $this = $(this);

    // adicionar a mim um atributo "title" com o valor do meu texto
    $this.attr("title", $this.text());
});
```

---

## Refatoração da solução

O @bfavaretto alertou para o facto de que o código apresentado como solução pode ser optimizado e reduzido mantendo o mesmo objectivo final.

Assim sendo, ficam as duas formas que visam reduzir e optimizar a solução previamente apresentada:

1. #### Redução

   Aqui estamos a reduzir a operação de localizar os elementos com a classe `.title-texto`, aplicando por cada encontrado, um atributo `title` com o texto contido no mesmo:

   [**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/CZ5Xp/)

   ```
   $(".title-texto").attr("title", function(){ return $(this).text(); });
   ```
2. #### Optimização

   Aqui, pegando no código após redução, estamos a optimizar a operação realizada retirando a rê-pesquisa do elemento no DOM realizada pelo `$(this)`, fazendo uso do JavaScript `this` aplicando o `this.textContent` ou `this.innerText` consoante o suporte do navegador:

   [**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/FL2PQ/)

   ```
   $(".title-texto").attr("title", function(){ return this.textContent || this.innerText; });
   ```

Comment: É exatamente isso que estava procurando; com isso vou economizar muito tempo... Muito obrigado pela ajuda.